# Ad shows with a scrollbar

Tags: android, admob

I've added an ad to my app according to [this](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/incorporating-android-admob-ads-into.html) guide with SDK v6.
The ad it is shown with a vertical scrollbar (and actually scrolls a bit) both on 2.3 & 4.0.
How to remove it?

TIA.
[image: ad img]

Comment: It's probably because the creative is slightly too big.  Does this happen all the time?  Does this happen with the test ad?

Comment: Yes, all the time & with test ads as well.

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce this.  I'm guessing you have wrap_content on the AdView.  Does this not happen on other versions of Android, or are you only just testing on 2.3 and 4.0?